# MAX and COUNT function doesn't work together

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I want to count id_r and then return the maxim value of count using

```
 MAX(COUNT(id_r))
```

but shows me this error

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3tDm.png)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(e1) as Expr1 FROM (
SELECT COUNT(id_r) as e1
FROM Angajat) as t1
```

`COUNT(id_r)` wil return only 1 result since there is no group by clause. Hence, there is no use of max.

You need to add a group by clause in subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(e1) as Expr1 FROM (
SELECT column1, COUNT(id_r) as e1
FROM Angajat
GROUP BY column1
) as t1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use one aggregation function at a time.

The ANSI standard way to do what you want is:

```
select count(*) 
from t
group by ?
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Or alternatively a subquery:

```
select max(cnt)
from (select count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by ?
     ) x;
```

Note that you want a `group by` of something, perhaps `id_r`.